# WSO2 PHP framework is intermittently not decrypting response

Tags: php, soap, encryption, wso2

My PHP service consumer has been running for a couple of years without any problems and there have been no changes but for the last week, the service response is sometimes not decrypted. Or at least that's how it seems.

The same code, using the same certificates will produce a readable xml response when using "object(WSMessage)->str" one moment and encrypted data the next.

I've used $client->getLastResponse() and this is showing the encrypted data in the soap body which is normally decrypted at that stage.

Is there anyway to retrieve the message before decryption?

Or does anyone know why this might be occuring?

Comment: Could the message be getting double encrypted? Meaning that when you decrypt you still end up with an encrypted result. Also, without some sort of code to look at, I doubt anyone here will know why your application just stopped working as expected.

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors? Check the webserver error logs. Have you tried crafting a few test messages that you pass in and check the response? Are you getting the same message back, garbage or does it look like a different encrypted message? Have there been any changes to the server? Many shared hosting services will update software packages without telling (or they post somewhere and expect you look it up).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I know I'm asking a lot to ask for help when there isn't an awful amount to go on. I might get lucky and someone has had the same experience with wso2. I've been looking through logs for over a week and can't see anything obvious. I do have test code on the same server pointing to the producers test environment and that also, intermittently shows the same issue.

Comment: The producer says there have been no changes on their end.

Comment: WSO2, from what I can tell, is a generic framework for communicating between web services. It should have nothing specific that would have broken. How are the messages encrypted/decrypted? Using what method (i.e. mcrypt) and algorithm?

Comment: I agree. The service is using ws-security - I can't think of any reason a certificate would only intermittantly work so I don't think it's the certificates but I am questions everything now. I've even installed SoapUI and am trying to run test requests from that, when a problem occurs, hoping that SoapUI will also capture the invalid response and I can say for sure that the problem is at the producer but so far, SoapUI hasn't captured a problem. I don't think that means it's definately a consumer problem either though because of the intermittant nature of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm glad to say I've finally got to the bottom of this and I hope this will stop anyone else going through the same.
Part of the WS-Security required a timestamp in the header information.
Now I don't know if the producer server time had slipped forward or my consumer server time slipped backwards but intermittantly, when the network was nice and quick, the timestamp in the response was ahead of the consumer server time by 1 second or so and this caused the WSO2 framework to not decrypt the message rather than advise of the timestamp discrepency.